CouponManagement Plugin not working on cart page
I have created a plugin to add custom functionaly before Coupon apply it's working fine on checkout page but not working on cart page:
/etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement">
        <plugin name="checkout_coupon_apply" type="Geekay\Rewardpoint\Plugin\CheckoutCouponApply"/>
    </type>

/Plugin/CheckoutCouponApply.php
<?php 
    
    namespace Geekay\Rewardpoint\Plugin;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
    class CheckoutCouponApply {
    
            protected  $_customerSession;
            protected  $_cart;       
            protected  $_rewardHelper;
            protected  $_jsonFactory;
            protected  $_rule;
            protected  $_storeManager;
            protected  $_coupon;
            protected $logger;
            public function __construct(       
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
                \Geekay\Rewardpoint\Helper\Data $asplHelper,
                \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
                \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule,
                \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon $coupon,
                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
            ) {            
                $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;       
                $this->_cart = $cart;                
                $this->_rewardHelper = $asplHelper;
                $this->_jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
                $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
                $this->_rule = $rule;
                $this->_coupon = $coupon;
                $this->logger = $logger;
    
            }
        public function beforeSet(\Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement $subject, $cartId, $couponCode)
        { 
    // code here
    }
    }

What's wrong here?

Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement will not work on cart page because on cart page a separate controller is calling i.e vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/CouponPost.php
On checkout page, API (http://{{m2url}}/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/coupons/1234
) is triggering and calling Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement set method
You also need to adjust execute method from controller
Hope above will help!
